# AngularJs: View is not displaying data even though the data is present in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller and view and want to display properties of the productCategory object in the view. Even though the productCategory is present in the controller, it is not displayed in the view.

Controller:

```
angular.module('jordans')
    .controller('productCategoryCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, dataService) {
        $scope.productCategories = [];
        $scope.currentData = {};
        $scope.productCategory = [];

        $scope.getCategories = function () {
            dataService.getProductCategories().then(function (data) {
                $scope.productCategories = data;
//                    console.log('productCategories = ' + JSON.stringify($scope.productCategories));
            })
        }

        $scope.getCategory = function () {
            $scope.productCategory = dataService.getProductCategory($scope.currentData);
            console.log('productCategory = ' + JSON.stringify($scope.productCategory));
        }

        $rootScope.$on('setcategory', function (e, args) {
            console.log('******** ' + new Date());

            $scope.currentData.category = args.category;
            $scope.currentData.type = args.type;
            console.log('*******productcategory.currentdata = ' + JSON.stringify($scope.currentData))
            $scope.getCategory($scope.currentData);
        });

        var init = function () {
            $scope.getCategories();
        };

        init();

    })
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller='productCategoryCtrl' ng-hide="data.error">
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <img src="..\assets\images\{{productCategory.image[0].name}}">
    <p class="categoryheading">{{productCategory.image[0].label}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="productImage in productCategory.image">
        <div ng-if="$index > 0">
            <div class="col-sm-4 typemargin">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img src="..\assets\images\{{productCategory.image[i].name}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <p><b>{{productCategory.image[$index].label}}</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that productCategory is array and you're doing ng-repeat on productCategory.image[0] and you can't access that, you could probably access productCategory[0].image[0].

You should probably loop through all productCategory array and then put your code. So just do ng-repeat on entire block like :

```
<div class="col-sm-10" ng-repeat="prodCat in productCategory">
```

...and then use prodCat inside div block instead of productCategory.

Also just a hint, not related to your problem, when you're using console.logs don't use concatenation with + just use comma , i.e.

```
console.log('productCategory', $scope.productCategory);
```

this way you won't need jsonstringify and you'll get nice object that you can interact with in console.

Also another posiblity is that you just need productCategory[0].image, I don't really know your test object so it's just a guess.